# Creating a simplistic ListView in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I am using a `ListView` in my UWP app. I want a very simplistic `ListView` which has no animations and does not respond to `hover`, `selection` etc. So I am using the ListView control as:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="False"/>
```

Though this does most of the things for me. But I have one more requirement, I do not want the bulging of the top and bottom of the border of my `ListView` elements when I hover over them as highlighted in red in the following screenshot:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygqWI.png)

Is there any way I can avoid this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend just using an `ItemsControl` instead.  Then build up around it what you need.  If there's nothing the `ListView` offers that you're using then it's just a bloated `ItemsControl` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

try using this :

```
<ListView SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="False"  >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

All It does is reduce the visual tickness ( top and bottom ) to 0 making it disappear and hides the visual selection. Hope this solves your problem ?